# Build on base of commit message condition or changed since last successful

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have multibranch with following code, i want that pipeline should start building only if

- if commit message doesn't contain word like "INTERIM"
- or how i can check "changed since last successful Build" condition

  ```
  pipeline {

   agent any

   stages {
        stage('Build') {
           when { changelog '.*INTERIM' }
           steps {
               echo 'I am building '+scm.branches[0].name+' branch.'
               sh "echo Shell ${CHANGE_author}"
               echo "echo Shell ${CHANGE_author}"
           }
       }
   }
  }
  ```

First condition is working but how i can achieve second?